# Delphi 2009 Crashes on CreateServiceW (only in windows 2008 R2)

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, windows-server-2008-r2

I have the following code which runs fine on all operating systems (32 & 64 bit) except for Windows 2008 R2 (SP0 & SP1)

```
fSvcMgr := OpenSCManagerW(PwideChar(FOptions.ComputerName), nil,
      SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);
    if fSvcMgr = 0 then
    begin
      iserror := true;
      RaiseLastWin32Error;
    end;
...
fSvc := OpenServiceW(fSvcMgr, pwidechar(Service_name),SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);
if fSvc = 0 then
begin
  fSvc := CreateServiceW(fSvcMgr,
          pwidechar(Service_name),
          pwidechar(Service_name),
          SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS, 
          SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,
          SERVICE_DEMAND_START,
          SERVICE_ERROR_IGNORE,
          pwidechar(fServiceName), nil, nil, nil, nil, nil);
  if fSvc = 0 then
  begin
     iserror := true;
     RaiseLastWin32Error;
  end;
end;
```

**This happens when connecting to a remote 32 bit machine:**

While debugging delphi crashes on the CreateserviceW line with message 'Application-defined exception (code 0x000006d1) at ... process stopped.
try/except around the createserviceW doesn't make any difference.

**When connecting to a remote 64 bit machine everything works fine!**

Comment: Are you sure your handle to scm is valid? Please show more code...

Comment: Handle is valid, extra code added

Comment: I have found the problem: somewhere else in the code I used "ADsEnumerateNext" without using "ADsFreeEnumerator", this never gave any problems except for this particular case (only in win2008R2) (found the problem by accident)

Answer (score 0):

The error is also apparent on Microsoft SBS Server 2011.

The problem your experiencing seems to be based on elevation, you are not running the application in the scope of a user with the correct elevation.

Have you tried adding a manifest to your application to ensure it is correctly elevated, in addition for the purpose of testing you may wish to compile the application (caller) and run with the credentials of an administrator.

Its important to note that Microsoft Windows 2008 and 2011 have a scope limitation, where as you can not interact with a process, or service at a lesser or greater level than yourself. This security feature has caused many headaches.

As such, if you **have** elevation, try without.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with UAC enabled and disabled, with requireAdministrator uac.manifest and without (the problem is the same)

Comment: @WilfriendVS - Can we have some more code please, as I can not reproduce this issue once the UAC considerations have been taken into account.

Answer (score 0):

The call to CreateService generates an RPC call to either [RCreateServiceW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245923%28PROT.13%29.aspx) or [RCreateServiceWOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc245925%28v=PROT.13%29.aspx). The RPC Call returns you 0x000006d1 which stands for RPC_S_PROCNUM_OUT_OF_RANGE and it means that the underlying RPC layer fails (the requested opnum doesn't exist). It could be a bug...

Comment: I tried embedding the advapi32.dll file from windows 7 - 32 bit and running CreateService from this DLL, the error is the same.  It could be related to a security feature as Reallyethical is suggesting.